# Can't add Silverlight App with "Enable .NET RIA Services" to existing project

Tags: .net, silverlight, ria

I can create new Silverlight App with ".NET RIA Services" enabled.

But when I try to add Silverlight App into existing solution in the "New Silverlight Application" the "Enable .NET RIA Services" checkbox is disabled.

Why? How can I add Silverlight App into existing solution?

Thanks.

P.S. Environment description: Win Vista x64, VS2008, Silverlight Toolkit 3.0, RIA Services.

P.P.S. For the client project (added without this checkbox enabled) I opened "properties" page, and ".NET RIA Services link" dropdown list is empty (it contains "No Project Set" item).

Probably the reason is in the fact that I need to convert my "web-application" from "usual asp.net web-site" to "web-project"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in type of the web-site: Silverlight Client requires to be linked to web-project only.

So here is the solution: convert existing web-site into web-project and then use new project for Ria Services.

Help with migration: http://webproject.scottgu.com/VisualBasic/Migration2/Migration2.aspx